# Disabling the Close-Button temporarily

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to disable *just* the close button (minimize and maximize should be allowed) temporarily.

Every solution I've tried disables *all* the buttons or just disables the close button permanently. Is there a way to do it temporarily?

Comment: handle the `Closing` event instead, just remember that you can't stop task manager

Comment: aside from indeed handling the `Closing` event you should consider dealing with the decissions of the user - if he wants the window closed then close it and handle the consequences

Comment: I also agree with Carsten here, try not to force the user to do anything. Encourage them to "do the right thing"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way to *permanently* disable the close button is to set the [`CS_NOCLOSE` style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729176.aspx) for the form's window class. To do this from a WinForms application, you override the form's [`CreateParams` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.createparams.aspx) and add the `SC_NOCLOSE` flag using the `|` operator, e.g.:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        const int CS_NOCLOSE = 0x200;
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ClassStyle = cp.ClassStyle | CS_NOCLOSE;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

This is a permanent solution, though, since you cannot update window class styles on-the-fly. You would have to destroy and recreate the window class.

However, you can instead disable the "Close" command in the system menu, which also also automatically disables the close button in the title bar.

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    public const int SC_CLOSE     = 0xF060;
    public const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0;
    public const int MF_ENABLED   = 0;
    public const int MF_GRAYED    = 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool revert);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, int IDEnableItem, int enable);
}

public class MyForm : Form
{

    // ...

    // If "enable" is true, the close button will be enabled (the default state).
    // If "enable" is false, the Close button will be disabled.
    bool SetCloseButton(bool enable)
    {
        IntPtr hMenu = NativeMethods.GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, false);
        if (hMenu != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            NativeMethods.EnableMenuItem(hMenu,
                                         NativeMethods.SC_CLOSE,
                                         NativeMethods.MF_BYCOMMAND | (enable ? NativeMethods.MF_ENABLED : NativeMethods.MF_GRAYED));                                
        }
    }   
}
```

Note that this really is a transient operation. If you do *anything* that causes the system menu to be modified by the framework (such as maximizing or minimizing the form), your modifications will be obliterated. More details are in [my related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932933/why-are-maximize-minimize-events-causing-the-close-button-to-be-re-enabled-after/4591962#4591962). This is normally a problem, and why you'd prefer to use the first solution. But in this case, since you want to dynamically disable and re-enable, it is no big deal.

Finally, do be mindful of the fact that what you're proposing runs counter to the [Windows UI Guidelines for dialog boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742499.aspx). They say, in essence, that users expect to see a close button and that its presence gives them a feeling of security that they can always safely "get out" of whatever popped up of the screen. Thus, you should not disable it. It does call out a progress dialog as an exception, but it goes on to say that a progress dialog should always have a "Cancel" button that allows aborting the operation. In that case, you can simply make the close button in the title bar invoke this "Cancel" button—no need to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may be possible, I have never seen it. That's just not how programs do it and your program should follow known patterns so it's users know how to use it.

If closing a program is temporarily not possible, show a message explaining why, when your user tries. This way you can present a solution ("you must first do...") instead of simply presenting a problem ("cannot be closed").

In addition, there are multiple ways to close a form. You are only looking at one of them. Disabling one will still leave the others and you would want to prevent *all* options that lead to closing your window, so it's best to handle the `Closing` event appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The Close Button Is Disabled On Below Conditon :
If We Add : MessageBoxButtons.YesNo

```
DialogResult Dr = MessageBox.Show(this, "", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
isprocessing = true;
form.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(form_cancel); 
private void form_cancel(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if (isprocessing)
   {
      e.Cancel = true;  //disables the form close when processing is true
   }
   else
   {
      e.Cancel = false; //enables it later when processing is set to false at some point 
    }
}
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide it, but you can disable it:

```
private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
       CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
       myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON ;
       return myCp;
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20379/Disabling-Close-Button-on-Forms

If you absolutely need to hide it, the only way to do it is to create a borderless form, then draw your own minimize and maximize buttons. Here is an article on how to do this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42223/Easy-Customize-Title-Bar

Before considering either of these solutions, you should maybe rethink why you need to do this. Depending on what you are trying to do, there is probably a much better way to present the UI to the user other than taking away the familiar 'X' close button.

Comment: *Definitely* don't hide it! Closing it is bad enough, but there are arguments to be made for it in certain cases. Entirely removing it, on the other hand, is *extremely* disorienting for the user. In general, you want to disable commands that are not applicable, rather than removing them.

Answer (score 0):

Using Win32 API, you can do this the following way:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetClassLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern uint SetClassLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong);

private const int GCL_STYLE = -26;
private const uint CS_NOCLOSE = 0x0200;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var style = GetClassLong(Handle, GCL_STYLE);
    SetClassLong(Handle, GCL_STYLE, style | CS_NOCLOSE);
}
```

You will need to use [GetClassLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633580) / [SetClassLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633588) to enable the CS_NOCLOSE style. You then can remove it with the same operations, just use (style & ~CS_NOCLOSE) in SetClassLongPtr.

Actually, you can do this in WPF apps as well (yeah, I know, the question is about WinForms, but maybe someone will need this some day):

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    var style = GetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_STYLE);
    SetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_STYLE, style | CS_NOCLOSE);
}
```

Still, you should consider what others have suggested: just show a MessageBox or another kind of message to indicate that user should not close the window right now.

---

***Edit:***
Since window class is just a UINT, you can use GetClassLong and SetClassLong functions instead of GetClassLongPtr and SetClassLongPtr (as says MSDN):

> If you are retrieving a pointer or a handle, this function has been superseded by the GetClassLongPtr function. (Pointers and handles are 32 bits on 32-bit Windows and 64 bits on 64-bit Windows.)

This resolves the problem described by *Cody Gray* regarding the absense of *Ptr funcs in 32-bit OS.

Comment: This code has several issues. First of all, 32-bit operating systems do not export a `GetClassLongPtr` or `SetClassLongPtr` function. Those are only macros in the SDK headers. You have to P/Invoke the appropriate function depending on which architecture you are targeting. Second, when toggling this style on-the-fly, you must invalidate the form's non-client area to ensure that the visual state of the close button is changed. And invalidating the non-client area is tricky—the window manager makes a lot of assumptions for optimization purposes.

Comment: Finally, it is worth noting that setting the `CS_NOCLOSE` style *does not* disable the Close item on the system menu. So it is still trivial to close the window, either by using the system menu or by double-clicking the title bar icon. This *might* be what you want, but it probably isn't.

Comment: @CodyGray, well, this is much the same solution as setting `CreateParams.ClassStyle`. The invalidation of the non-client area seems to be done by the operating system itself as it successfully works when trying multiple disable/enable operations with the timer (in fact, I think this is the same as setting usual Button's Enabled property). But you're definitely right regarding 32-bit OS, this must be considered when implementing this solution.

Comment: @CodyGray, it seems that you can simply use `GetClassLong` and `SetClassLong` instead since the window's style is just a UINT. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, no, the window class style is not "just a UINT". It is a UINT_PTR, which means that it changes size according to the width of a pointer on that platform. So you do need to pay attention to the bitness of the architecture you're compiling for, that's why the Ptr-suffix macro exists.

Comment: And I'm surprised to hear you say that you see the close box being updated. When I tried your code (using a button to toggle instead of a timer) on both Windows XP and Windows 7, I didn't see an update until I forced the window to redraw manually.

Comment: @CodyGray, hm, according to MSDN, the [WNDCLASSEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633577) structure contains a `UINT` member called `style` that accepts the flags representing the window's style. I didn't look into the Windows SDK headers though. And regarding redraw, I checked it both on WinForms and WPF apps, and both were disabling/enabling correctly. Though those were AnyCPU assemblies compiled without "Prefer 32-bit" setting on the x64 OS.

Answer (score 0):

As per other answers you are working against the guidelines and framework but, if you really must, one work around would be to put all your form content into a Usercontrol and then pass that between form instances that  either have the close button enabled or disabled on load.

So as you trigger the disable or enable of the close button you create a new form instance in which the close button is toggled and then pass in the reference to your usercontrol, then dereference the usercontrol in the current form and transfer to the new form.

You'd likely get a some flicker as you did this. Terrible idea IMHO but it is "an" option.

Comment: I decided to choose the most User-Friendly method to solve this problem. I have chosen to handle the FormClosing-Event and cancel the Event as long as i have to while it gives a MessageBox as a feedback so that the user knows whats up